# How to get the event onText Change of a input (type ="file") box

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
<input id="url" type="text" value="blab.ogg"/>
<input id="fileUrl" type="file" size="1" onblur="document.getElementById('url') =  this.value"/>
```

i need to set the same text in `fileUrl`, into `url` if somebody inserts a file by file chooser.

what is the event which triggers the dynamic change in text in input.

Comment: what do you mean by file url. do you want to add with the url . An example would be helpufl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `onchange` event:

```
<input id="fileUrl" type="file" size="1" 
onchange="document.getElementById('url').value =  this.value"/>
```

Also, as you can see, you should assign the file input value to the value of the url input:

```
document.getElementById('url').value =  this.value
```